# Making a form goto a random position and staying within the screen size - Windows forms

Tags: winforms

Hi I'm making a subliminal message program where I have a form that appears then disappears very quickly.

I am now trying to figure out how I can make it so each time it pops up, that it's in a random location but most importantly what I'm struggling with is making it so it stays within the borders of someone's screen size.

I have been struggling to find the relevant code and also seen something about using Width to set the control but I can't find out what is meant by the control either.

Hoping to be pointed in the right direction

Thanks.

Comment: Simply restrict the random results to some (the screen dimensions)  vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the form size programmatically, set the form's `StartPosition` property to `Manual`.

You can get the screen size with

```
Rectangle screen = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
```

You also need a `Random` object. Make sure to only create it once, e.g. by making it static and read-only.

```
private static readonly Random _random = new Random();
```

Now you can get random positions and open the form with

```
var frm = new MySubliminalForm();
int x = _random.Next(screen.Width - frm.Width);   // range [0 .. screen width - form width].
int y = _random.Next(screen.Height - frm.Height); // range [0 .. screen height - form height].
frm.Location = new Point(x, y);
frm.Show();
```

---

This shows the screen (big rectangle) and the window (small rectangle) at its maximum position. As you can see, the window's X-position is the screen width minus the window width and the Y-position is the screen height minus the window height.

```
+------------------screen width------------+
|                           :              |
|                           :              |
|       screen              :              |
|                        y = Hscr - Hwin   |
|                           :              |
|                           V              |
| .....x = Wscr - Wwin ...> o-window width-+
|                           |              |
|                           |   window     |
|                           |              |
+---------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks worked very well, I don't fully understand how taking the screen.width away from the frm.width prevents it from going off screen. I've seen similar examples in game design and wasn't able to understand it then. If  you have the chance could you point me in the right direction of figuring out how it works please

Comment: It's simple: the window's position is its top left corner. The bottom right corner of the windows is equal to its position plus its size. Since you don't want the bottom right corner to be off screen, subtract the window size from the screen size to get the maximum possible window position.

Comment: I didn't get the explanation at first but then looking again into what random.next does it makes sense now, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: `_random.Next(N)` yields an `int` in the range `0 .. N - 1`.