# Form opens in a random position in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I wanted to make that form would open in a random position on a screen.
I found the similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51314375/19160533
But i didnt get how to implement this.
Im using Delphi 11.
Thanks!

Comment: When the form is created, you could set the form.Left to a random number between 0 and screen width - form.width and then do the same for form.Top.

Comment: If you want to make it appear randomly each time you click, you should use LEFT/TOP properties from form.

Comment: What about using [``TForm.Position``](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Position) set to ``poDefaultPosOnly``!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the top and left of the form on FormShow:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  self.Top := Random(1000);
  left := Random(2000);
end;
```

for a better result, you can calculate the desktop dimensions and subtract the form width and height.

Comment: Correct, but why the "self" reference for top, and not for width? that's a bit confusing AFAICT

Comment: The predefined variable `self` is referring to the current object like `this` in c#. It isn't necessary.

Comment: I know. But you can omit the `self.` or add it for the width too. This looks a bit messy.